# Dotnet core CORS - PATCH method is not being included in Access-Control-Allow-Methods

Tags: .net-core, cors

I have been trying to enable cors for a patch method in dotnet core webapi.

I tried the following code:

```
services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder =>
        {              
            builder
                .AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod();
        }));
```

also tried `.WithMethods("PATCH","GET")`

and adding it to pipeline as `app.UseCors("CorsPolicy")` before `app.UseMvc()`

My Options call request header:

`Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method: PUT
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Referer: http://localhost:3000/
Sec-Fetch-Mode: no-cors
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36`

It returns 204-No-Content with following headers.

`Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Date: Tue, 17 Sep 2019 10:59:23 GMT
Request-Context: appId=cid-v1:46d7928d-c15f-4a2f-bded-4035f2eaba1f
Server: Kestrel`

The value of **Access-Control-Allow-Methods** in response header would always be "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS". There would be no PATCH whatever I try.

Same Code works fine with Internet Explorer and returns **Access-Control-Allow-Methods** with method names I mention in WithMethods("PATCH", "GET") method.

Comment: you should also add `app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");` before UseMVC in `Configure` method on `Startup.cs`

Comment: @MasihAkbari Yes i am adding that.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the call to `AllowAnyMethod()` altogether, and adding the other REST verbs to `WithMethods()`:

```cs
services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder =>
    {              
        builder
            .AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .WithMethods("GET", "PUT", "PATCH", "POST", "DELETE", "OPTIONS");
    }));
```